# Pair Apple Watch again without erasing

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, apple-watch

I have accidentally unpaired my Apple Watch on my iPhone. I need to pair my watch with the same iPhone again.

(But I think the same problem can probably be faced if one gets a new iPhone with an already paired watch.)

The Apple Watch is fully working. I can open the apps, see my clock-face and so on. But in the menu bar, there is a red strikethrough iPhone icon.

If I open the Apple Watch app on my iPhone and tap on start pairing, my Apple Watch does not show the pairing image as it did first after unboxing it.

Do I need to completely erase my watch or is there somehow an option to start pairing my watch again?

According to my space usage on my iPhone (Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage), I do have a backup on my iPhone. But this is some days ago and I do not want to lose my (activity) data – so erasing my watch is really my last choice.

To put it in a nutshell: **How do I pair my iPhone with my watch again without erasing it?**

Comment: Un-pairing makes a backup of the watch onto your phone, then erases the watch. So if you're still seeing third-party apps installed prior to the un-pairing, then it may not actually be un-paired. What appears on your watch and phone when you tap on Start Pairing on iPhone?

Comment: I have the same problem. My phones he went haywire so I wiped it. My watch is fine but has a red phone at the top. When I try to pair manually in the phone watch app nothing shows in the list

Comment: @Jan I think your issue is different from Rafe's. For you, toggle Bluetooth off for a few seconds on the phone, then back on, and see if that resolves the connection problem.

Comment: @Rafe Toggle Bluetooth as described in my previous comment. You may have a further issue since your phone was wiped, and may need to set your Watch up as new, but it is probably the Bluetooth issue first.

Comment: Did you unpair the watch in Settings > General > Bluetooth on your iPhone, or did you just go out of range? That icon appears when you are out of bluetooth range of the iPhone, but it is still paired.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this problem when i had my phone on my desk and I would walk away from it. When I came back I found that the watch would refuse to re-pair with my phone again.

I found a quick way to force the watch to re-pair with my phone:

- Flick up on the watch face to get to the "Glances" menu
- Tap the airplane button to turn on Airplane mode
- Tap the airplane button again to turn off airplane mode
- Within a few seconds the watch will re-pair with the phone

Comment: The walk-away disconnect isn't the same as "unpairing"; it's just a normal disconnect.  "Unpair" has to do with when the phone forgets about the watch's device ID and doesn't auto-reconnect when you walk within range.  The issue is: re-pairing requires you to erase your watch.  Ex: I have several weeks of record-setting activity that I'd rather not lose, so I'm hoping to re-pair without reseting (erasing) my watch, but the phone seems uncooperative.

Answer (score 1):

Disable and re-enable Bluetooth on your iPhone. This fixed the issue for me. (This answer is just to give more visibility to the comment above by @tubedogg saying the same thing.)